# Using a callback when handling TCP connections with Tokio

Tags: callback, rust, lifetime, rust-tokio

I am trying to have a struct that starts an event loop, listens for TCP connections and calls a callback for each connection.

(The callback will be handed some prepossessed data from the socket.  In my example below I just hand it the IP address of the connection but in my real code I will parse the contents that I receive with `serde` into a struct and pass that into the callback.  I hope that doesn't invalidate the following "not working example").

My `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "lifetime-problem"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"
[dependencies]
tokio-tcp = "0.1.3"
tokio = "0.1.14"
[[bin]]
name = "lifetime-problem"
path = "main.rs"
```

and `main.rs`:

```
use tokio::prelude::*;

struct Test {
    printer: Option<Box<Fn(std::net::SocketAddr) + Sync>>,
}

impl Test {
    pub fn start(&mut self) -> Result<(), Box<std::error::Error>> {
        let addr = "127.0.0.1:4242".parse::<std::net::SocketAddr>()?;
        let listener = tokio::net::TcpListener::bind(&addr)?;
        let server = listener
            .incoming()
            .map_err(|e| eprintln!("failed to accept socket; error = {:?}", e))
            .for_each(move |socket: tokio::net::TcpStream| {
                let address = socket.peer_addr().expect("");
                match self.printer {
                    Some(callback) => { callback(address); }
                    None => { println!("{}", address); }
                }
                Ok(())
            });
        tokio::run(server);
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = Test{ printer: None };
    x.start();
}
```

I have tried several things starting from this code (which is adopted directly from the [Tokio example](https://tokio-rs.github.io/tokio/tokio/net/tcp/struct.TcpListener.html#examples)).

1. If I use the code like posted above I get:

   ```
   error[E0277]: (dyn std::ops::Fn(std::net::SocketAddr) + std::marker::Sync + 'static) cannot be sent between threads safely
   ```

   for the line 24 (`tokio::run(server)`).
2. If I add the `Send` trait on the `Fn` in the printer field *XOR* if I remove the `move` in the closure in the `for_each` call I get another error instead:

   ```
   error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
   ```

   which points me to the closure that apparently cannot outlive the `start` method where it is defined but `tokio::run` seems to have conflicting requirements for it.

Do you know if I am addressing the callback pattern in totally the wrong way or if there is just some minor error in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first:

Compiler will translate `Box<Fn(std::net::SocketAddr) + Sync>` to `Box<Fn(std::net::SocketAddr) + Sync + 'static>` unless the lifetime is explicitly specified.

Let's have a look at the errors:

```
error[E0277]: (dyn std::ops::Fn(std::net::SocketAddr) + std::marker::Sync + 'static) cannot be sent between threads safely
```

This is self-explanatory. You are trying to move `&mut T` to another thread, but cannot, because `T` here is not `Send`. To send `&mut T` to another thread `T` too needs to be of type `Send`.

Here is the minimal code that will give the same error:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

fn func<T> (i:&'static mut T) where T: Debug {
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("{:?}", i);
    });
}
```

If I make `T` above to also be of type `Send`, the error goes away.
But in your case when you add the `Send` trait, it gives lifetime error. Why?

`&mut self` has some lifetime greater than the function `start()` set by the caller, but there's no guarantee that its `'static`. You move this reference into the closure which is passed to the thread and can potentially outlive the scope it is closing over, leading to a dangling reference.

Here's a minimal version, that would give the same error.

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

fn func<'a, T:'a> (i:&'a mut T) where T: Debug + Sync + Send {
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("{:?}", i);
    });
}
```

`Sync` is not really required here as it is `&mut T`. Changing `&mut T` to `&T` (retaining `Sync`), will also result into the same error. The onus here is on references and not mutability. So you see, there is some lifetime `'a` and it is moved into a closure (given to a thread), which means the closure now contains a reference (disjoint from the main context). So now, what is `'a` and how long will it live from the closure's perspective that is invoked from another thread? Not inferable! As a result, the compiler complains saying `cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements`.

If we tweak the code a bit to;

```
impl Test {
    pub fn start(&'static mut self) -> Result<(), Box<std::error::Error>> {
        let addr = "127.0.0.1:4242".parse::<std::net::SocketAddr>()?;
        let listener = tokio::net::TcpListener::bind(&addr)?;
        let server = listener
            .incoming()
            .map_err(|e| eprintln!("failed to accept socket; error = {:?}", e))
            .for_each(move |socket: tokio::net::TcpStream| {
                let address = socket.peer_addr().expect("");
                match &self.printer {
                    Some(callback) => { callback(address); }
                    None => { println!("{}", address); }
                }
                Ok(())
            });
        tokio::run(server);
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

it will compile fine. There's a guarantee there that `self` has a `'static` lifetime. Please note that in the `match` statement we need to pass `&self.printer`, as you cannot move out of a borrowed context.

However, this expects `Test` to be declared static and that too a mutable one, which is generally not the best way, if you have other options.

Another way is; if it's ok for you to pass `Test` by value to `start()` and then further move it into `for_each()`, the code would look like this:

```
use tokio::prelude::*;

struct Test {
    printer: Option<Box<Fn(std::net::SocketAddr) + Send>>,
}

impl Test {
    pub fn start(mut self) -> Result<(), Box<std::error::Error>> {
        let addr = "127.0.0.1:4242".parse::<std::net::SocketAddr>()?;
        let listener = tokio::net::TcpListener::bind(&addr)?;
        let server = listener
            .incoming()
            .map_err(|e| eprintln!("failed to accept socket; error = {:?}", e))
            .for_each(move |socket: tokio::net::TcpStream| {
                let address = socket.peer_addr().expect("");
                match &self.printer {
                    Some(callback) => {
                        callback(address);
                    }
                    None => {
                        println!("{}", address);
                    }
                }
                Ok(())
            });
        tokio::run(server);
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = Test { printer: None };
    x.start();
}
```

Comment: I have cargo/rust 1.32.0 and it told me I can leave out the `mut` for `self` in the signature of `Test::start(self)` and thus also on `x` in the main function.

Comment: @Lucas, yes, That's up to you. If you think `Test` will never get mutated, there's no need of `mut`.